# Convert float to std::string in C++

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have a float value that needs to be put into a `std::string`. How do I convert from float to string?

```
float val = 2.5;
std::string my_val = val; // error here
```

Comment: Consider reading Herb Sutter's article "The String Formatters of Manor Farm" (http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm).  It provides examples of five of the most common ways to format things and discusses their advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Unless you're worried about performance, use [string streams](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt):

```cpp
#include <sstream>
//..

std::ostringstream ss;
ss << myFloat;
std::string s(ss.str());
```

If you're okay with Boost, [lexical_cast<>](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) is a convenient alternative:

```
std::string s = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(myFloat);
```

Efficient alternatives are e.g. [FastFormat](http://www.fastformat.org/) or simply the C-style functions.

Comment: This will be an adequate solution considering that these functions will be called rarely (resizing the window), but is there a more efficient method?

Comment: And if you're not okay with Boost, write your own lexical cast function; it's all of about five lines of code and makes for a most useful library function (see http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm for the basic implementation).

Comment: For the first method, don't forget `#include <sstream>`.

Comment: @jackw11111, The header is a very important point that is all to often omitted from answers.  It is especially problematic with c++ 'streams'.  Thanks for pointing it out.  I was going to do so if you had not.

Answer (score 165):

As of C++11, the standard C++ library provides the function [`std::to_string(arg)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/) with various supported types for `arg`.

Comment: Be aware of possible unexpected behaviour of std::to_string() when working with floats.
(See output of examples on this link http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: this deserves to be promoted to the best answer because most build enviornment would have C++11 support already

Comment: Following up on @MichaelKonečný's comment, quoting the same page, which got this update since then: _C++17 provides `std::to_chars` as a higher-performance locale-independent alternative._

Answer (score 31):

**Important**:
Read the note at the end.

**Quick answer:**

Use `to_string()` (available since [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11))
example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    string pi = "pi is " + to_string(3.1415926);
    cout << "pi = " << pi << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Run it yourself: http://ideone.com/7ejfaU

These are available as well:

```
string to_string (int val);
string to_string (long val);
string to_string (long long val);
string to_string (unsigned val);
string to_string (unsigned long val);
string to_string (unsigned long long val);
string to_string (float val);
string to_string (double val);
string to_string (long double val);
```

**Important Note:**

As @Michael Konečný rightfully pointed out, using `to_string()` is risky at best that is its very likely to cause unexpected results.
From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string:

> With floating point types `std::to_string` may **yield unexpected results** as the number of significant digits in the returned string can be zero, see the example.
> The return value may differ significantly from what `std::cout` prints by default, see the example.
> `std::to_string` relies on the current locale for formatting purposes, and therefore concurrent calls to `std::to_string` from
> multiple threads may result in partial serialization of calls. `C++17`
> provides `std::to_chars` as a higher-performance locale-independent
> alternative.

The best way would be to use `stringstream` as others such as @dcp demonstrated in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2125908/2736559):

This issue is demonstrated in the following example:
run the example yourself: https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/T4k

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

template < typename Type > std::string to_str (const Type & t)
{
  std::ostringstream os;
  os << t;
  return os.str ();
}

int main ()
{
  // More information: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string
  double f = 23.43;
  double f2 = 1e-9;
  double f3 = 1e40;
  double f4 = 1e-40;
  double f5 = 123456789;
  std::string f_str = std::to_string (f);
  std::string f_str2 = std::to_string (f2); // Note: returns "0.000000"
  std::string f_str3 = std::to_string (f3); // Note: Does not return "1e+40".
  std::string f_str4 = std::to_string (f4); // Note: returns "0.000000"
  std::string f_str5 = std::to_string (f5);

  std::cout << "std::cout: " << f << '\n'
    << "to_string: " << f_str << '\n'
    << "ostringstream: " << to_str (f) << "\n\n"
    << "std::cout: " << f2 << '\n'
    << "to_string: " << f_str2 << '\n'
    << "ostringstream: " << to_str (f2) << "\n\n"
    << "std::cout: " << f3 << '\n'
    << "to_string: " << f_str3 << '\n'
    << "ostringstream: " << to_str (f3) << "\n\n"
    << "std::cout: " << f4 << '\n'
    << "to_string: " << f_str4 << '\n'
    << "ostringstream: " << to_str (f4) << "\n\n"
    << "std::cout: " << f5 << '\n'
    << "to_string: " << f_str5 << '\n'
    << "ostringstream: " << to_str (f5) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
std::cout: 23.43
to_string: 23.430000
ostringstream: 23.43

std::cout: 1e-09
to_string: 0.000000
ostringstream: 1e-09

std::cout: 1e+40
to_string: 10000000000000000303786028427003666890752.000000
ostringstream: 1e+40

std::cout: 1e-40
to_string: 0.000000
ostringstream: 1e-40

std::cout: 1.23457e+08
to_string: 123456789.000000
ostringstream: 1.23457e+08
```

Comment: Be aware of possible unexpected behaviour of std::to_string() when working with floats.
(See output of examples on this link http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Answer (score 17):

You can define a template which will work not only just with doubles, but with other types as well.

```
template <typename T> string tostr(const T& t) { 
   ostringstream os; 
   os<<t; 
   return os.str(); 
}
```

Then you can use it for other types.

```
double x = 14.4;
int y = 21;

string sx = tostr(x);
string sy = tostr(y);
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [`std::to_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars) once your standard library provides it:

```
std::array<char, 32> buf;
auto result = std::to_chars(buf.data(), buf.data() + buf.size(), val);
if (result.ec == std::errc()) {
  auto str = std::string(buf.data(), result.ptr - buf.data());
  // use the string
} else {
  // handle the error
}
```

The advantages of this method are:

- It is locale-independent, preventing bugs when writing data into formats such as JSON that require '.' as a decimal point
- It provides shortest decimal representation with round trip guarantees
- It is potentially more efficient than other standard methods because it doesn't use the locale and doesn't require allocation

Unfortunately `std::to_string` is of limited utility with floating point because it uses the fixed representation, rounding small values to zero and producing long strings for large values, e.g.

```
auto s1 = std::to_string(1e+40);
// s1 == 10000000000000000303786028427003666890752.000000

auto s2 = std::to_string(1e-40);
// s2 == 0.000000
```

C++20 might get a more convenient `std::format` API with the same benefits as `std::to_chars` if the [P0645](http://wg21.link/p0645) standards proposal gets approved.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**std::to_string**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) in C++11

```
float val = 2.5;
std::string my_val = std::to_string(val);
```

Comment: Heads up, don't copy-paste-submit-grace_period_edit answers. copy-paste-edit-submit them. We get an auto flag instead. Take care the next time. Cheers

Comment: This is basically identical to @dmckee's answer from 2013.

Comment: @Yochai when I `cout` the `my_val` gives 5.20000 but when you assigned `val` to 50.2 or more bigger then it gives not accurate output. Gives like: 50.000001 and 107.199997 (for 107.2). whats the reason of this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about performance, check out the [Boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) library.

Comment: I think you mean "if you're *not* worried about performance".  `boost::lexical_cast` is about the heaviest solution you could pick!

Answer (score -1):

[This tutorial](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/convert-num-to-string.html) gives a simple, yet elegant, solution, which I transcribe:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

class BadConversion : public std::runtime_error {
public:
  BadConversion(std::string const& s)
    : std::runtime_error(s)
    { }
};

inline std::string stringify(double x)
{
  std::ostringstream o;
  if (!(o << x))
    throw BadConversion("stringify(double)");
  return o.str();
}
...
std::string my_val = stringify(val);
```