# Prevent the zero before the decimal from being displayed in C++

Tags: c++, output, setf

In C++, I'm using the following statements to display output:

```
// example
float x = 0.66004;
cout.setf(ios::fixed);  
cout.setf(ios::showpoint);  
cout.precision(2);
cout << x;
```

My output looks like

```
0.66
```

How can I prevent the zero before the decimal from being displayed? I want:

```
.66
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::string Foo = std::to_string(0.553);
std::size_t it = Foo.find(".");

if (it != std::string::npos)
{
    std::cout<<Foo.erase(0, it);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought about using a string. Thought there might be some kind of setf modifier for this.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is converting `x` to string ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125880/converting-a-float-to-stdstring-in-c) options) and cut off everything before the decimal.