# Change a file name including char and float

Tags: c++

I'm working on a C++ code, but I'm having some problems since I have never used this language before.

The structure of my project (.pro) file contains different .ccp files, including:

`IOFile.cpp` : where the file name I want to change is;

`CModel.cpp` : where there is the model of my project and, particularly, the parameter (float), chosen by user each time, that I would like to use for my file name.

So, for now the output name is something like: filename.txt, but I would like to rename it in order to obtain in somthing like filename_parameter.txt (for example: file_0.998.txt).

The void of my `IOFile.cpp` is written like:

```
void IOFile::saveIntensityMap(const char* fileName, vector<float>* intensityMap)
{
   std::ofstream file(fileName, std::fstream::out|std::fstream::trunc);

}
```

whereas the parameter (ray_factor) is initialized in the `CModel.cpp` file:

```
ray_factor= 0.99f
```

So, how could I pass the ray_factor, that is in `CModel`, to the `IOfile`? And how can I write a filename that includes a string and a float?
Sorry for the silly question, but I can't find a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert float to std::string in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125880/convert-float-to-stdstring-in-c)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your post doesn't provide enough information to solicit constructive answers.  For example, you don't show how or where  `saveIntensityMap` is actually called, nor how or where `filename` is constructed. When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [SO help here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a silly question, and there's a *ton* of bad advice on this particular subject out there.

First, to get the `ray_factor` into `saveIntensityMap`, simply pass it as another argument:

```
void IOFile::saveIntensityMap(const char* fileName,
                              float ray_factor,
                              vector<float>* intensityMap)
{
   ...
}
```

Second, forget you ever heard of formatted iostreams output, it is enormously more trouble than it's worth.  (This is the part where there's lots of bad advice on the 'net.  I personally never use iostreams at all; I think the old-fashioned `<stdio.h>` API is a much more ergonomic interface.  Writing a floating-point number into a string with proper control over the output format is one of the things that iostreams are especially bad at.)

To construct the filename you want, use `snprintf` to format the number and concatenation of `std::string` objects to assemble the name, like this:  (note that I am assuming the `fileName` argument to `saveIntensityMap` does *not* have the `.txt` extension already - it will probably be easier to change that than to take the string apart and put it back together; C++ is not really very good at strings)

```
char ray_factor_buf[10];
snprintf(ray_factor_buf, sizeof ray_factor_buf, "%.2f", ray_factor);

string full_filename = fileName;
full_filename += "_";
full_filename += ray_factor_buf;
full_filename += ".txt";

std::ofstream file(full_filename, std::fstream::out|std::fstream::trunc);
```

If your C++ library has not yet been updated to C++11, that last line will need to be

```
std::ofstream file(full_filename.c_str(), std::fstream::out|std::fstream::trunc);
```

Comment: If going with `snprintf` then why not skip `std::string` altogether? `snprintf(.., "%s_%.2f.txt",..)`

Comment: @Dialecticus Because then you have to allocate memory by hand.  If `asprintf` is available, that's not a problem, but otherwise it's fiddly and easy to get wrong.